# Find first date in string

Tags: php, date-parsing

I have a pdf file which i parsed using "pdfparser" plugin. From the text of the pages i need to find first date after a specific string (search string). I can find the search string and for date extraction i used

```
date_parse($string)
```

it extracts the date, month fine but i think due to the large string (with some more dates, numbers) it didn't populate the correct year, it gives a random number which is not even present in doc.

Is there any other way to get that date . Following is the example string.(it has more date after the date)

```
Satisfaction of the mortgage from Karen Ann Lewis,a single woman to Bank of America, N.A. recorded March 4, 2004
```

Comment: https://eval.in/930330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following RegEx (to extract the first date in the format you've provided), and then use `parse_date()`:

```
$str = 'Satisfaction of the mortgage from Karen Ann Lewis,a single woman to Bank of America, N.A. recorded March 4, 2004';

preg_match("/(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}/", $str, $matches);

var_dump( date_parse($matches[0]) );
```

The above outputs:

```
array(12) {
  ["year"]     => int(2004)
  ["month"]    => int(3)
  ["day"]      => int(4)
  ["hour"]     => bool(false)
  ["minute"]   => bool(false)
  ["second"]   => bool(false)
  ["fraction"] => bool(false)
  ...
}
```

[**Demo here**](https://eval.in/930325)

Comment: thanks, it works but is there any option that if the date format changes

Comment: Well, I’m afraid that you will need to write a new RegEx.

Comment: @nOmi Yes, exactly.

Comment: i used date_parse to get the first 2 and regex to extract the year, this way at least day and month are getting populated for each format.